# Assigning Unique IDs

Tags: google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet of tasks, each of which I'd like to assign an ID to (in column A). Each task falls within certain categories (contained in column B), and the ID should relate to this category. For example, if the category is '4', then the first ID should be 04.01, and the second task should be 04.02 etc. Are there any formulas that would work well here and ensure that each ID is unique?

The category is a lookup based on the value in column C, so at the moment my formula is:

```
=vlookup(C1,Lookups!A:B,2,false) & "." & text(row(C1:C) - row(C1) + 1, "00")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sample data would have been helpful, but UNTESTED might be worth trying:

```
=vlookup(C1,Lookups!A:B,2,0)&"."&text(countif(C$1:C1,C1),"00")
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks :)